# Android getting score when questions are in different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im creating an app consisting of a PlayActivity with 3 fragments (3 questions). 
The fragments are accessed by clicking imagebuttons (in PlayActivity).
The questions have an EditText (user inputs their answer).

I want the app to check if the answer is correct, if so user gets one point. In the end a button can be clicked and user will be taken to a new page showing the score.

But what should the code for the points be? 
Ive tried with SharedPreferences, but almost all tutorials for this is with button clicks instead of edittext.

Comment: when will you start checking answer? after clicking on something or automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you trying SharedPreferences you can cast the string inside edittext to int and add it up.
But depend on the scale of each level you can pass data to another fragment using Intent

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Retrieving that information you need to get the arguments sent to the fragment.

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); 
if (bundle != null) {
        int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue); 
}
```